# MVVM/Presentation Model With WinForms

Tags: winforms, data-binding, mvvm, model, presentation

I'm currently working on a brownfield application, it's written with winforms,
as a preparation to use WPF in a later version, out team plans to at least use the 
MVVM/Presentation model, and bind it against winforms...

I've explored the subject, including the posts in this site (which i love very much),
when boiled down, the main advantage of wpf are :

- binding controls to properties in xaml.
- binding commands to command objects in the viewmodel.

the first feature is easy to implement (in code), or with a generic control binder, which binds all the controls in the form.

the second feature is a little harder to implement, but if you inherit from all your controls and add a command property (which is triggered by an internal event such as click), which is binded to a command instance in the ViewModel.

The challenges I'm currently aware of are :

- implementing a commandmanager, (which will trigger the CanInvoke method of the commands as necessery.
- winforms only supports one level of databinding : datasource, datamember, wpf is much more flexible.

am i missing any other major features that winforms lacks in comparison with wpf, when attempting to implement this design pattern?

i sure many of you will recommend some sort of MVP pattern, but MVVM/Presentation model is the way to go for me, because I'll want future WPF support.

Thanks in advance,
Erik.

Comment: Have you considered just using an ElementHost to drop new WPF content into your existing WinForm app?

Comment: I'll probably do that at some point...
I've thought of another challenge: DataTemplates..

instead of using datatemlates, i'll use a usercontrol and bind it againt an object on my viewmodel.. :))

I'll start working on a prototype next week, anyone interested in my results?

Comment: This post may be useful to those looking for a CommandManager implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685088/binding-to-commands-in-winforms

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [Update Controls .NET](http://updatecontrols.net). It is an open-source library for Winforms, WPF, and Silverlight that keeps controls up to date as data changes. You can start using it now for Winforms, and then transition over to WPF without changing your Data Model or View Model code.

Unfortunately, it does not solve the Winforms command binding problem. Your button click events will not port from Winforms to WPF. But it does take care of the data binding problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the **[WAF Windows Forms Adapter](http://waf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Downloads&referringTitle=Home)** interesting. It shows how to apply the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) Pattern in a Windows Forms application. The Adapter implementation provides a solution for the missing **Command** support in Windows Forms.