# Proper usage of MVVM ICommand in WinForms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, mvvm

I'm using `MVVM` in `WinForms` application (I don't know WPF). I'm also using [Dave Kerr library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM) it is very good wrapper around ICommand. It supports asynchronous command, event binding and more.

In his examples he is using `XAML`:

```
<Button Content="Asynchronous Command" Command="{Binding AsyncCommand1}" />
```

I'm using:

```
public class Class1 : ViewModel
{
    private AsynchronousCommand _command;
    public BinaryData BinaryData;

    public Class1(Foo config)
    {
        _command = new AsynchronousCommand(() =>
        {
            BinaryData = ...
        });

        _command.DoExecute(null);
    }

    public AsynchronousCommand Command
    {
        get { return _command; }
    }
}

_vm = new Class1(_config);
_vm.Command.Executed += Command_Executed;
```

and in `Command_executed`

```
var response = _vm.BinaryData;
```

Is it OK? Or there is some `.Net` class that do the actually binding like real `Button`?

Comment: winforms does not support MVVM. Learn WPF.

Comment: Technically MVVM is just a design pattern, and can be used with any technology. It works best for WPF because of WPF's binding system, and it may not be the ideal design pattern to use for WinForms. You might want to try MVP instead. But anyways, I don't think WinForms buttons support binding a `Command` and `CommandParameter` properties, so you'll probably want to hook up your `Button.Click` method to call `_vm.Command`.

Comment: "winforms does not support MVVM" ??? No no no. Like Rachel said it is simply a design pattern that can used with any technology but works best with WPF. ICommand is not a requirement for MVVM. My advice is to learn WPF like HighCore said. Trust me it'll be worth your time.

Comment: Up: current project is WinForms. MVVM suits me for separating UI from rest of code. ICommand (especially Asynchronous) is good for call Service and (with Event) ping back UI. I know Win buttons don't support Command. But .cs can support it?

Comment: @TMan can you show me `any` examples of how to do something like a `DataTemplate` in winforms? or even a complex property Binding like `{Binding Order.Customer.Address}` or the like?

Comment: @tomasito in contrast to Rachel, who is really a sane, polite, sensible, trustworthy person, I'm a complete jerk. I say: forget winforms, it's completely useless. If you need something usable, put an `ElementHost` in your (existing?) winforms app and use it to host usable, customizable, useful WPF content, or use pure WPF.

Comment: @HighCore In new project (this is new project) new for me are: MVVM and ServiceStack. I must use something familiar. Otherwise I'll stuck for eternity.

Comment: @Tomasito you'll be stuck for eternity trying to fit `winforms` to MVVM. It simply does not fit. horrible winforms fits with horrible, procedural, horrible, useless code behind. beautiful XAML-based technologies such as WPF fit with beautiful MVVM.

Comment: @Tomasito BTW, winforms is not recommended for any new projects, only to maintain legacy applications. It's a really old technology no one cares about anymore. It does not have hardware acceleration, it does not allow any kind of customization without resorting to a bunch of horrible hacks. It does not allow testability by separating UI from application logic, and it is not XAML-based, which means you can't eventually port your  winforms code to newer technologies such as WinRT XAML.

Comment: @HighCore Next project will be written using something more recent.

Comment: @Tomasito then you should leave MVVM for your next project.

Comment: Just to add 2 cents - and I'm dealing with a WinForms project now that I refuse to let it die: we can [bind commands to buttons through the Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1763715/2752308)!