# ReactiveUI 6.0 and WinForms binding

Tags: c#, winforms, reactiveui

Now that ReactiveUI 6.0 [has been released](http://log.paulbetts.org/welcome-to-reactiveui-6-0/), I have a question to the commuity: what is the best or most efficient way to bind ReactiveObject(s) and Windows Form(s).

Here is what I have so far:

*My Model*

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    #region

    using System;
    using System.Reactive.Linq;

    using ReactiveUI;

    #endregion

    public class ClockModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        #region Fields

        private DateTime currentDateTime;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors and Destructors

        public ClockModel() { Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Subscribe(s => this.CurrentDateTime = DateTime.Now); }

        #endregion

        #region Public Properties

        public DateTime CurrentDateTime
        {
            get { return currentDateTime; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref currentDateTime, value); }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

*My only form*

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        readonly ClockModel model = new ClockModel();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", model, "CurrentDateTime");
        }
    }
}
```

It does work, but I am not thrilled about referring to properties on each side by their string names. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

**UPDATE 1**

Given [this extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301809/workarounds-for-nameof-operator-in-c-typesafe-databinding):

```
public class NameOf<T>
{
    public static string Property<TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expression)
    {
        var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (body == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("'expression' should be a member expression");
        return body.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Is this form any more desirable than the previous one?

```
this.label1.DataBindings.Add(NameOf<Form1>.Property(e => e.label1.Text), model, NameOf<ClockModel>.Property(p => p.CurrentDateTime));
```

**UPDATE 2**

Another extension:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetPropertyName<T,TProp>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expression)
    {
        var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (body == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("'expression' should be a member expression");
        return body.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Now I can use:

```
this.label1.DataBindings.Add(this.GetPropertyName(e => e.label1.Text), model, model.GetPropertyName(p => p.CurrentDateTime));
```

or this:

```
this.label2.DataBindings.Add(this.label2.GetPropertyName(e => e.Text), model, model.GetPropertyName(p => p.Ticks));
```

I start to like this one, but what do others think of any of the three approaches?

Technically speaking, the Form became a View and a Controller or Presenter, while the Model is still separated and has no knowledge of its consumers. Would this be preferred approach?

**UPDATE 3**

This might cause some purists a mild heart attack ...
Based on Paul Betts advice:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    #region

    using System.Windows.Forms;

    using ReactiveUI;

    #endregion

    public partial class Form1 : Form, IViewFor<ClockModel>
    {
        #region Constructors and Destructors

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ViewModel = new ClockModel();
            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.CurrentDateTime, v => v.label1.Text);
            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Ticks, v => v.label2.Text);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Properties

        public ClockModel ViewModel { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Explicit Interface Properties

        object IViewFor.ViewModel
        {
            get { return ViewModel; }
            set { ViewModel = value as ClockModel; }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Interesting change in behavior: prior to Update 3, time was displayed with seconds. I can only reason that this is due to the default ReactiveUI converter used in the third approach. I have to learn more about it.

```
public class DateTimeStringConverter : IBindingTypeConverter
{
    public int GetAffinityForObjects(Type fromType, Type toType) { return 1; }

    public bool TryConvert(object @from, Type toType, object conversionHint, out object result) { 
        result = ((DateTime)@from).ToString("F");
        return true;
    }
}
```

I like the elegance of the approach.

Any other opinions?

Comment: Looks like you can easily create an extension method for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use ReactiveUI bindings - implement `IViewFor<TViewModel>` on your Form, then you will get several new methods such as `Bind` and `OneWayBind`.

Check out https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/docs/docs/basics/bindings.md for more information

Comment: Paul, thanks for the response. Are there any examples yet how to associate a converter with the binding? Googled for ReactiveUI conversionHint, but can't find anything on the first three pages.

Comment: You need to implement `IBindingTypeConverter` and register it via `Locator.CurrentMutable.Register`

Comment: I understand, that part. What I am looking for is an example for the converter code, and how it is supposed to be integrated with the view. That part is unclear. On a separate note, I like the WPF approach, where there is Convert and CovertBack. The intent is much clearer I think.

Comment: Here's a simple example: https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI/Xaml/BindingTypeConverters.cs#L24

Comment: Broken links. :-(