# Two Way Data Binding without XAML

Tags: c#, .net, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a class that I want to use to update a textbox when one of its properties changes. I also want to be able to change the classes property when the textbox changes. In other words, I want to be able to have two-way databinding. I have looked online, and all the example require a XAML file. As I am not familiar with XAML, I would like to stay away from that if it is possible.

Is it possible to have a two-way databinding with a class without using XAML?

Update:

I found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, and it seems to work. However, I do not entirely understand what it is doing.

More specifically, I do not understand how PropertyChanged and OnPropertyChanged relate to each other.

Comment: is it a WPF application?

Comment: No, it is a WinForm (C#) application.

Comment: Do you mind using the ReactiveUI framework? While I haven't used it for WinForms it has support for it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768640/reactiveui-6-0-and-winforms-binding

Comment: You need to learn about C# events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# WPF you get PropertyChanged when you implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

So, if you write

```
PropertyChanged(this,  new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PersonName"));
```

You give the Observer (XAML) the Signal that the Property `PersonName` changed and it will update all e.g. UIElements linked to that Property.

With

```
 protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
  {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
  }
```

you overload the name of the Property (e.g. PersonName) as a string to signal which Property has changed.

With the `if(handler != null)` you say that you only send the signal if there is any Observer.

If so, in the next line you really give the Signal.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling I was getting PropertyChanged from the INotifyPropertyChanged. When is the Observer created?

Comment: As soon as a UIElement in XAML has a Binding on this Object e.g. the Text Property of a TextBox